# How to create a chm file?

Tags: chm

What is the best way to create a chm file?

if possible, Could someone provide opensource tools for this job?

Comment: It's really not too helpful to users to just vote to kill a topic because it doesn't comply with Stack Overflow rules regarding questions with subjective answers without any further action. This is a good question that's simply in the wrong place and it would be much more useful to move it to Meta and include a link to the question's new location in the "Closed as off-topic" announcement.

Answer (score 22):

You can download the tools from here [HTML Help Workshop and Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138)

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 20):

You could try [KEL CHM Creator](http://dumah7.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/kel-chm-creator-v-1-4-0-0/).

It's free, easy and it works.

It supports HTML keywords for building the index, tools for automatic TOC construction, CHM decompilation, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Html Help Workshop tools from Microsoft. Its free.

[Microsoft Help Documentation with links to the downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/microsoft-html-help-1-4-sdk)