# How to export from Wikimedia to CHM file?

Tags: plugins, documentation-generation, chm, wikimedia

I would like to export some pages in my Wikimedia project to a CHM file. I thought about using a plugin for a browser or something like that, but I haven't found anything. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO, a site for programming questions! So, where is yours?

Comment: @Joel If you know any plugin that generates a CHM file that spans the entire wiki. Or another option to generate the CHM file. Sorry if i didn't explain properly

Comment: This site is for questions about making programs, not finding them

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft HTML Help Downloads, which can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138).

Other (maybe) relevant SO questions:

[How to create a chm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993166/how-to-creating-a-chm-file)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023/what-are-good-tools-for-creating-compiled-html-help-files-chm