# Want to create chm file from website html pages

Tags: html, chm, html-help

I have some html pages which are integrated with a web site. Now the requirement is to create a .CHM file for the required pages.

To do this task manually will take a huge amount of time.
Please help me to extract the only html files from the website without getting its css, js or other files. Because, I do not want other files except .html.

I will use those html files and create .CHM file.

The main purpose of this task is to create online help.

Your answer will be appreciated a lot.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993166/how-to-creating-a-chm-file

Answer (score 2):

Creating online help - also known as help authoring - is a task with a learning curve. It is not clear to me why you want to extract the .css and .js. I think you will need the .css e.g. in your online help project later.

A CHM file can be thought of as a zipped (compiled) web site. The content pane of the help viewer on the right displays the content like a browser window. If you want to see the same formatting by .css as on your web site you'll have to integrate these .css files into the CHM file.

And this may become a time consuming task depending of your web site structure and coding inside of your HTML files e.g. the CSS links. A scenario could be to copy the HTML files, make a new .css and change the CSS links as needed (maybe by FAR with "Find And Replace") for a structured "sub web" as described below for preparing the CHM compile task.

On the Internet you can find many (some expensive) tools to create CHM files.
One of my favorite freeware tool is FAR HTML (https://www.help-info.de/far-html.html).
It's recommended - the wizards are great and FAR HTML has a 30-days full working trial. To quickly manipulate HTML files, or author help Projects FAR HTML will save you lots of time.

It's required to install Microsoft [HTMLHelp Workshop](https://www.help-info.de/download.html) (see download on top).

One tip - don't look at all the options of FAR when starting.

1. Copy your HTML files to structured subfolders of your project folder e.g.:

   ```
     welcome.htm 
     design.css 
     First_Steps\download.htm 
     First_Steps\starting_program.htm 
     How_to_extend\extend_menu.htm 
     How_to_extend\power_function.htm 
     images\gui_screenshot.jpg
   ```
2. Drag and drop these files to FAR HTML
3. Start the wizard for HTMLHelp 1.x
4. ready ..

Comment: In my source files there are four folders like:
-data, images, javascripts, and stylesheet. And, other html files
when I click the index.html and any other html file, its opens in browser like a web page (with menus, drop-down menu) and works very well.

But, I want to displays these files data in chm file as a Help.

Comment: @Anant : I want to recommend giving the help authoring process a first try with some simple HTML and CSS files like shown in the tip above. In a second step, this first experience must then be transferred to your needs and existing web page structure. Some sample files you may download from: http://www.help-info.de/files_download/chm_example_files.zip . If you want the resulting CHM file without your existing menus and drop down menus, this will be a lot of work. Another solution is trying to add the main functionality of a CHM with Table of Contents, Index and Search as additional function.

Comment: @Anant : Is your web page online or Intranet only?